# How to change the variables so $x_{n+3}=f(x_{n},x_{n+1},x_{n+2})$ becomes of the form $g(y_n)=y_{n+1}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems

How to change the variables so $x_{n+3}=f(x_{n},x_{n+1},x_{n+2})$ becomes of the form $g(\underline{y}_n)=\underline{y}_{n+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\underline{y_{n+1}}=g(\underline{y_n})=g(x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2})=(x_{n+1},x_{n+2},f(x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2}))$